# I am having a problem to fetch and display a single item in Flutter from API

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-getx, flutter-futurebuilder

I have an endpoint that returns data in the following JSON format.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "balance": "40.000000"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to display the above balance into a wallet UI. I am having difficulty to display a single element that is not using controller formfield.
Below is additional code:

**wallet_service.dart**

```
Future<ApiResponse> getWalletBalance() async {
  ApiResponse apiResponse = ApiResponse();
  try {
    String token = await getToken();
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(wallet),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
        });

    switch(response.statusCode){
      case 200:
        apiResponse.data = Wallet.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));

        break;
      case 401:
        apiResponse.error = unauthorized;
        break;
      default:
        apiResponse.error = somethingWentWrong;
        break;
    }
  }
  catch (e){
    apiResponse.error = serverError;
  }
  return apiResponse;
}
```

**walletui.dart**

```
class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {

  Wallet? wallet;
  bool loading = true;
  GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  //TextEditingController txtBalanceController = TextEditingController();
  //int mybalance=0;



  // get user detail
  void getUserWallet() async {
    ApiResponse response = await getWalletBalance();
    if(response.error == null) {
      setState(() {
        wallet = response.data as Wallet;
        //log('data: $wallet');
        loading = false;
        //txtBalanceController.text = wallet?.balance?? '';

      });
    }
    else if(response.error == unauthorized){
      logout().then((value) => {
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Login()), (route) => false)
      });
    }
    else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text('${response.error}')
      ));
    }
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    getUserWallet();

    super.initState();
  }
}
```

**Wallet Model Class**

```
class Wallet {
  int? id;
  String? balance;

  Wallet({
    this.id,
    this.balance,
  });

  factory Wallet.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return Wallet(
      id: json['id'],
      balance: json['balance'],
    );
  }
}
```

My goal is to store the balance in a variable wallet that I can execute in the UI and display that value.

Comment: Can you please also include the code of your `Wallet` class?

Comment: @ S. M. JAHANGIR added

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this link call for api:https://github.com/JayswalViraj/Flutter-Login-With-Rest-API

Please you understand after implemente.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Dude , am not looking for authentification advice @ Jayswal Viraj.Seems you did not get what I asked